# Type name in form element, creates signature

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am looking for a way so that when a user types their name within a form field input box, a digital signature is created, or some type of box that shows the name written.

Is something like this possible?

The form itself does not need to submit the signature, it is purely for show on the form page itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for changes on your input and on each trigger, copy it's value to the place you want. That's what you want to achieve, right?

```
// Listen for input change
$('#yourInputId').on('input',function(e){
   //copy it's content somewhere else
   $('#placeToPasteValue').text($('#yourInputId').val());
});
```

EDIT: I don't know your exact case, but if you want to show/hide some other elements based on input value, you can check if input is empty

```
// Listen for input change
$('#yourInputId').on('input',function(e){
   var currentInputValue = $('#yourInputId').val();
   if(currentInputValue === '') {
       $('#otherElement').hide();
   } else {
       $('#otherElement').show();
       //copy it's content somewhere else
       $('#placeToPasteValue').text(currentInputValue);
   }

});
```

Other approach could be to add/remove your CSS classes inside if/else block to provide transitions, or other fancy effects :)

Comment: Simple & yet so effective. Thank you

Comment: How would you have it so the #placeToPasteValue here is hidden until something is written? I would want to set the box to have a different background colour etc, and not to be displayed until they begin typing their name within the field input.

Comment: @user3642210 I've updated my answer, hope it will help :)

Comment: Ok, the #otherElement is probably not required, as all I need to do is hide #placeToPasteValue until something is written in #yourInputID - thanks though... you have been a great help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need but maybe can help

```js
var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
var nameField = document.getElementById("name");
var sign = document.getElementById("sign");

function createSign(){
  sign.innerText = nameField.value;
}

button.addEventListener("click",createSign,false);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive);

div{
  height:300px;
  width:80%;
  font-family:"Cedarville Cursive";
  font-size:25pt;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
<button value="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
<br>
<div>
   <p id="sign"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this... the example above, where the text is displayed before submitting was what I was looking for. Thank you very much though for your assistance! :)